# A closed set A and compact set B in a topological vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis

I don't believe this is a repeat question. I have seen it asked before on here, but not in this way.

If I take a closed set $A$ in a topological vector space $X$ and a compact set $B$ also in $X$, is there a way to show that $A + B$ is closed using nets?

I have seen it done and am very familiar with the proof using regular and open sets, but I'm looking for an excuse to use nets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a net $\{a_\alpha + b_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ with $a_\alpha \in A$ and $b_\alpha \in B$ that converges to $c$. We need to show $c \in A + B$.  Since $B$ is compact, 
there is a subnet $\{b_\beta\}_{\beta \in J}$ converging to some $b \in B$.
Then $a_\beta = (a_\beta + b_\beta) - b_\beta$ converges to  $c - b$, and
since $A$ is closed this must be in $A$.  Thus $c = (c-b) + b \in A + B$.

Comment: Actually, how do we know the difference of two nets converges to the difference of their limits? Is that proven elsewhere?

Comment: Continuity of addition in a topological vector space.

Answer (score 0):

let $(s_i)$ be a net in $A+B$ with $s_i=a_i+b_i$ which converges to $x$, since $B$ is compact then there is a convergent subnet $(b_{h(j)})$, let us say that $b$ is the limit. Then $a_{h(j)}=s_{h(j)}-b_{h(j)}$ converges to $x-b$. Since $A$ is closed, we have that $x-b\in A$, hence $x\in A+B$. We conclude that $A+B$ is closed.